# How to Change Style of Parent <li> on Hover

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site (on my localhost) that uses a `<ul>` for a custom menu. How can I change the CSS of a `<li>` on hover **only** if it has a `<ul>` sub-menu?

All the main menu items have a border-radius and I want to remove this on the current item (Services, below) for example:

```
    <div class="main-nav">
      <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#>Item Two</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I can't find a CSS solution and I've tried jQuery too:

```
    $('ul.sub-menu').parent().hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('no-radius');
});
```

Comment: may you can do this with pure css also please show your css for more

Comment: That would be a great option. Dev site is here http://haizdesign.com/mim/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.menu li').has('ul').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, more elegant than mine +1

Comment: Thanks - I'm still not getting a result with this on my localhost for some reason - all my other jQuery is working! Here's where I have a dev version online: http://haizdesign.com/mim/

Comment: It's not on my live dev site, only my localhost version.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say what is wrong with your html, but sample works: http://jsfiddle.net/gCJhj/1/

Comment: Thanks Samich - guess I'll be debugging this weekend!

Comment: Sorry for the late update - Samich, your code worked a treat. Now I've got to deal with IE and getting my .current-page class working with a border-radius! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".menu LI").hover(
    function() {
        if ($("UL", $(this)).length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("no-radius");
        }
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("no-radius");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
$("li").hover(function(){
if($(this).parent().hasClass("sub-menu") {
 $(this).css("color", "red");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li>ul.sub-menu').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('no-radius');
}, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('no-radius');
});
```

In Your solution `this` refers to the `ul` item and not its parent.

Instead this piece of code checks if any `li` has a direct child of `ul` with class=`sub-menu` and then applies the desired class to the `li` element.

Hope it helps,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.sub-menu').parent().hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('no-radius');
});
```

You can always use console.debug($(this)) to check which element you are accessing