# Hover on nested item can affect its parent?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have a menu using pure CSS, hover a parent `li` item display the the nested list. A simplified example:

```
  <ul id="menu-top" >
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp5/forums/">Forums</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wp5/register/">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wp5/activate/">Activate</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wp5/members/">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The css:

```
.navigation ul.menu li:hover { background: #ccc} //hover the parent item changes it bg color

.navigation ul.sub-menu li {
 display:none;
}

.navigation ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu li { display: block; }
```

It works ok, but I'm trying to add an "persistent" effect, I want keep the parent style set when hovering also the sub-item.

I tried this but can't get working:

```
.navigation ul.sub-menu li:hover > .navigation ul.menu li { background: #ccc}
```

I don't know if this is possible without javscript or else, also can't find anything about using ">" in CSS.

THanks for any help

Comment: In CSS child items cannot affect their parents. Period.

Comment: @Diodeus, [yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject).

Comment: Thanks, I should know about parents :( Is possible to add a class with js then? I'm trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180378/how-to-change-style-of-parent-li-on-hover bu anything happens.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20greater%20than

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:hover` is triggered on all ancestors of the element that is being hovered over, so `.navigation ul.menu li:hover { background: #ccc; }` should work just fine.

Alternatively, someday we should be able to use [`:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational).

Comment: That's nice, at least for direct parent.

Comment: Solves the examples quite right :D but it will be useful rewriting some areas in the real menu I'm dealing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-item:hover {
     background-color:#ccc;
}
.sub-menu li:hover {
     background-color:#666;
}
```